# Swipe,js slide indicator

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement Swipe.js with an indicator below it so the user will know that there are more images in the slide and they will also know where in the slideshow they reached. I tried to do this it doesn't work anyone can indicate as to why this doesn't work? My code is below

jQuery

```
window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe'),{
                callback: function(pos) {

                var i = bullets.length;
                while (i--) {
                bullets[i].className = ' ';
                }
                bullets[pos].className = 'on';

            }}
var bullets = document.getElementById('position').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

HTML

```
<div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:300px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'id="featured">
    </div>
</div>

            <nav>
                <ul id="position">
                    <li class="on"></li>
                    <li class=" "></li>
                    <li class=" "></li>
                    <li class=" "></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Please note that I receive the images via ajax the link to the file am using is `https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe`

Answer (score 0):

At least I see here syntax error, that is not an error for JS parser, but looks like something different of you wanted to implement.

```
window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe'),{
                callback: function(pos) {

                var i = bullets.length;
                while (i--) {
                bullets[i].className = ' ';
                }
                bullets[pos].className = 'on';

            }}
```

Maybe wanted to be:

```
window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe({
  data : 'Swipe',
  callback: function(pos) {
    var i = bullets.length;
    while (i--) {
      bullets[i].className = ' ';
    }
    bullets[pos].className = 'on';
  }
});
```

Or something like that. There are a lot of JQuery.Swipe plugins, so provide a link to yours, please.

BTW, it is very strange idea to use getElementById, to manually iterate through collection of elements, to do all this mess when you have attached JQuery. Your code could be twice less.

Comment: add the url as u suggested.

Comment: So, at provided link I see this is not JQuery plugin at all. You can't use $( 'some selector' ).swype( some options hash ); construction.
Why don't you do the things exactly the way suggested in manual you provided?

Comment: Actually there is a jquery example in index.html page it is just commented out. Plus my swipe slideshow works its the bullet indicators that don't work

Comment: Ooops, I see:
Here in the bottom there is an example (commented):
https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/index.html

And here we see an JQuery plugin declaration (in the bottom):
https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/swipe.js

According to declaration the code in an example shouldn't work, but should work the idea I suggested in my first reply. Try this out please.